# Flutter ElevatedButton Custom style

Tags: flutter

I want to make an elevated button like the one below in Flutter. I have tried a few things like a border but did not succeed in it. How can I make it in Flutter?

[image]

I have tried following the code.

```
ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {},
   child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context).visualization_title)
)
```

In theme data

```
elevatedButtonTheme: ElevatedButtonThemeData(
    style: TextButton.styleFrom(elevation: 6,
              minimumSize: Size(double.infinity, 46),
              backgroundColor: Color(0xFF7F240F),
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 18, vertical: 18),
              side: BorderSide(color: Color(0xffC09E63), width: 3),
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6)),
              textStyle: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'JMHTypewriter',
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 20,
                  wordSpacing: 2,
                  letterSpacing: 2)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
                 Container(
                    color: Colors.deepOrange,
                    height: 100,
                    width: 200,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {  },
                        child: Text(""),
                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                            primary: Colors.deepOrange,
                            side: BorderSide(width:8, color: Colors.yellow)
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? What version of Flutter? What was it tested on (web server, browser, etc., all incl. versions) From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69718547/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code. Refer to the official documentation [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ElevatedButton-class.html) for the **ElevatedButton** Widget.

```
Container(
      color: Color(0xFF7F240F),
      height: 50,
      width: 200,
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            // Your Onpressed function here
          },
          child: Text("Submit"),
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            primary:Color(0xFF7F240F),
            side: BorderSide(
              width: 4,
              color: Color(0xffC09E63),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

Your result screen:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your *Elevated* button with *Container*:

```
Container(
          color: Color(0xFF7F240F),
          width: double.infinity,
          height: 46,
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5, vertical: 3),
          child: ElevatedButton(
            child: Text("test"),
            onPressed: null,
            style: ButtonStyle(
                shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                    RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
                        side: BorderSide( width: 3, color: Color(0xffC09E63))))),
          ),
        )
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is how the Elevated Button is used:

```
ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: () {},
    child: Text(""),
    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0, vertical: 8.0),
        onPrimary: Theme.of(context).primaryTextTheme.button.color,
        primary: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
        ),
    ),
),
```